# Sampling from k circles with different radii

Tags: python, random, numpy, computational-geometry

**Description:** I would like to sample `n_points` points from `k` circles whose radii and centers are given as lists.

**Note:** This is my first question :) And `k` is not a very large number, usually `k<7`.

**My code:** I guess the parts where I compute the number of points for each circle, and the for loop can be improved. *Perhaps* with a simple trick, the for loop can be removed, but I am not really sure. Any help to beautify the code is appreciated.

```
# given parameters
radii = [3,1,5]
n_points_total = 250
centers = [[3,0],[7,0],[13,0]]

# my code starts here
import numpy as np

r_sum = sum(radii) # proportional to total arc length
probabilities = [r/r_sum for r in radii] # probability of a point being in the i'th circle.
positions = np.random.choice(len(radii), n_points_total, p=probabilities) # each point is randomly assigned to a circle
n_points = np.unique(positions, return_counts = True)[1] # counts how many points each circle will contain


data = []

for n, center, r in zip(n_points, centers, radii):
    t = np.random.random(n)*2*np.pi
    x = r*np.cos(t) + center[0]
    y = r*np.sin(t) + center[1]
    data.append(np.vstack([x,y]).T)
    
data = np.concatenate(data)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works the way you want? `zip` is a "zip-shortest", and your arguments do not have equal length. `centers` has an outer dimension of 3; `radii` has 3; `n_points` has fewer (depending on the `n_points` parameter)

Comment: Rather the `n_points_total` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that your zip-shortest behaviour is intended.

`radii` and `centers` should immediately be made `np.ndarray`s. If they're fed from some external source like a file or stdin, there are easy ways to get them into arrays.

`import` at the very top, not after your givens.

Everything here can be vectorised. Avoid like the plague `for` loops, lists and iterative `vstack` calls.

First, recognise that your centres and radii are going to be repeated by the respective counts represented by the elements of `n_points`. This is exactly what `np.repeat` does.

Rather than indexing into the result of `np.unique()`, prefer tuple-unpacking.

Do not use `np.random.random`; that's deprecated. Prefer the new `Generator` stuff and call into `uniform` instead of post-multiplying.

Add unit tests with a predictable random seed.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from numpy.random._generator import Generator


def new(
    centers: np.array,
    radii: np.array,
    rand: Generator,
    n_points_total: int,
) -> np.ndarray:
    probabilities = radii / radii.sum()  # probability of a point being in the i'th circle.
    positions = rand.choice(a=len(radii), size=n_points_total, p=probabilities)  # each point is randomly assigned to a circle
    _, n_points = np.unique(positions, return_counts=True)  # counts how many points each circle will contain

    centers_spread = centers[:len(n_points)].repeat(repeats=n_points, axis=0)
    radii_spread = radii[:len(n_points)].repeat(repeats=n_points)

    t = rand.uniform(low=0, high=2*np.pi, size=n_points_total)
    cossin = np.empty_like(centers_spread)
    np.cos(t, out=cossin[:, 0])
    np.sin(t, out=cossin[:, 1])

    data = centers_spread + radii_spread[:, np.newaxis] * cossin
    return data


def old(
    centers: np.array,
    radii: np.array,
    rand: Generator,
    n_points_total: int,
) -> np.ndarray:
    r_sum = sum(radii)  # proportional to total arc length
    probabilities = [r / r_sum for r in radii]  # probability of a point being in the i'th circle.
    positions = rand.choice(len(radii), n_points_total,
                            p=probabilities)  # each point is randomly assigned to a circle
    n_points = np.unique(positions, return_counts=True)[1]  # counts how many points each circle will contain

    data = []

    for n, center, r in zip(n_points, centers, radii):
        t = rand.random(n) * 2 * np.pi
        x = r * np.cos(t) + center[0]
        y = r * np.sin(t) + center[1]
        data.append(np.vstack([x, y]).T)

    data = np.concatenate(data)
    return data


def test() -> None:
    centers = np.array((
        (3, 0), (7, 0), (13, 0),
    ), dtype=np.float64)
    radii = np.array((3, 1, 5), dtype=np.float64)

    for method in (old, new):
        rand = default_rng(seed=0)
        assert np.allclose(
            method(centers, radii, rand, n_points_total=10),
            np.array((
                (4.20619233, -2.74683455),
                (5.99955592,  0.05161697),
                (4.87431947, -2.34241895),
                (7.97781686,  0.20946168),
                (6.87251924, -0.99184104),
                (7.45031626,  0.89286912),
                (7.65268587, -0.75762864),
                (6.03374088, -0.25757196),
                (6.69270516,  0.95161435),
                (6.11568453,  0.46688988),
            )),
        )

        data = method(centers, radii, rand, n_points_total=250)
        assert data.shape == (250, 2)
        assert np.isclose(-4.999847197562797, data.min())
        assert np.isclose(17.99763106087105, data.max())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to add to the answer of @Reinderien, maybe a *slightly* different solution.

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_points_on_circles(radii, centers, num_pts):
    """
    usage:

    generate_points_on_circles(
        radii = np.array([3,1,1]), 
        centers = np.array([[3, 7, 13],
                            [0, 0, 0]]),
        num_pts = 10
    )
    """
    assert(radii.shape[0] == centers.shape[1] and centers.shape[0] == 2 and num_pts >= 0)

    circle_indices = np.random.choice(len(radii), num_pts, p=radii / radii.sum())
    
    angles = 2*np.pi*np.random.random(num_pts)

    return centers[:, circle_indices] + radii[circle_indices] * np.vstack([np.cos(angles), 
                                                                           np.sin(angles)])
```

This does assume row vectors, but you can always transpose with a `.T`. To keep the points grouped by the circle they are from, add a `np.sort` call to the line defining the circle indices.

Comment: This isn't equivalent, though, is it? It's a very different algorithm with very different results, and you don't offer much of a review on OP's original code (which is necessary for an answer to be on-topic).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Reinderien. As I've hinted at in my answer, I believe that you have already given a complete review, and I merely seek to offer a slightly different way of vectorizing things. I do not see my "algorithm" as all that different, but I do think that it's easier to tell what's going on. The output shouldn't be that different after the application of my closing comments, if this is desired.